# options.layout not working for sails.renderView()

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, layout, sails.js

After signup, I am required to send an email with activation URL. I am able to receive the required email. I want to improve the over-all code-base by setting-up a layout for all the emails. Following is the code snippet I wrote for this scenario:

```
// Send email for account activation
var options = {};
options.layout = sails.config.paths.views + '/emails/layout' + '.' + sails.config.views.engine.ext;
options.signupUrl = 'http://google.com';
options.name = newUser.name;

sails.log.debug(options);

sails.renderView('emails/signup', options, function (err, view) {
  EmailService.send({
      from: 'no-reply@service.com', // sender address
      to: 'to.msaads@gmail.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Activate your account', // Subject line
      html: view,
    },
    function (err) {
      if (err) { sails.log.error(err); }
    });
});
```

options.layout should use the specified layout, but it is not working as expected. The email I am receiving contains only the view 'emails/signup' without the layout '/emails/layout'.

Following are contents of 'emails/layout.ejs' file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<table style="height:100%;color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:rgb(239,239,239);" align="center">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:30px 0px" valign="top">
      <table style="border-collapse:collapse" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
        <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td valign="top" height="92">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="598" cellpadding="0" align="left" height="93" style="border:1px solid #FFFFFF;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;">
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="598" cellpadding="20" style="border-collapse:collapse;max-height:91px" height="93">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top">
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                          <img src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png" alt="Image" width="214" height="100" style="border-width:0px;border-style:none;max-width:214.83px;min-height:auto;width:100%" class="CToWUd">
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td valign="top" height="">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="598" cellpadding="0" align="left" height="" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;border-collapse:collapse">
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="598" cellpadding="20" style="border-collapse:collapse" height="">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" style="color:#3e3e3e;font-size:13px;font-family:'Trebuchet MS',Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:1.5">
                        <div dir="ltr" style="min-height:auto;display:block">
                          <div style="text-align:justify">

                            <%- body %>

                            <br><br>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Following are contents of 'emails/signup.ejs' file:

```
<h1>Welcome <%= name %></h1>
<div>You are now a member of this community. You can log in to your account with your email and password.</div>
<div>Please, click on the link below to <span class="il">activate</span> your account :</div>

<div>
  <br>
  <a style="display:block;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;background-color:#61c200;border:none;font-size:14px;padding:15px;border-radius:6px"
     href="<%= signupUrl %>">
    <span class="il">Activate</span> my account
  </a>
  <br>
</div>

<div><p>Let us know if we can ever be of assistance for anything!</p></div>
<div><p>Best,<br>The Team.</p></div>
```

**Note:** Under /config/views.js there is following line of code:

```
layout: false,
```

Because it is a single page app, and I don't require to have multiple layouts in my app.

Following is the relevant debug output:

```
debug:  layout=/home/user/project-folder/project-name/views/emails/layout.ejs, signupUrl=http://google.com, name=Saad
debug: Message sent: 250 2.0.0 OK 1471514431 v134sm30925433wmf.10 - gsmtp
```

**Question:** How can I properly setup layouts for all the other emails within SailsJS controller?

Comment: Did you try setting config.views.layout to true?

Comment: Yes. It is still not working with config.views.layout : true

Comment: Could it be an error in the path where you simply need a relative path, try:
options.layout = '/emails/layout';
or 
options.layout = '/emails/layout.' + sails.config.views.engine.ext;

Comment: I have tried both relative and absolute paths. Both are not working for me.

Comment: with and without the extension?